# Can all iterative algorithms be expressed recursively?

Tags: programming-languages, recursion, iteration, language-theory

Can all iterative algorithms be expressed recursively?

If not, is there a good counter example that shows an iterative algorithm for which there exists no recursive counterpart?

If it is the case that all iterative algorithms can be expressed recursively, are there cases in which this is more difficult to do?

Also, what role does the programming language play in all this? I can imagine that Scheme programmers have a different take on iteration (= tail-recursion) and stack usage than Java-only programmers.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.com/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There's a simple ad hoc proof for this.  Since you can build a Turing complete language using strictly iterative structures and a Turing complete language using only recursive structures, then the two are therefore equivalent.

Comment: Wow, food for thought. I envy all the upvoters that digested this more quickly than I did. Time to read up on this.

Comment: Wait, isn't that a logical fallacy? Circular reasoning?

Comment: C Bauer: Actually, it is not. The proof is very easy to do: assume languages IT (with iterative constructs only) and REC (with recursive constructs only). Simulate a universal turing machine using IT, then simulate a universal turing machine using REC. The existence of the simulator programs guarantees that both IT and REC can calculate all the computable functions. This property is proven for the lambda calculus, where all functions are partial recursive.

Comment: Alternately, build a Turing complete language using strictly (iteration/recursion), and in it write an interpreter for a Turing complete language using strictly (recursion/iteration).  Voila, whatever program you've written is being executed iteratively and recursively, simultaneously!

Answer (score 21):

> Can all iterative algorithms be expressed recursively?

Yes, but the proof is not interesting:

1. Transform the program with all its control flow into a single loop containing a single case statement in which each branch is straight-line control flow possibly including `break`, `return`, `exit`, `raise`, and so on.  Introduce a new variable (call it the "program counter") which the case statement uses to decide which block to execute next.

   This construction was discovered during the great "structured-programming wars" of the 1960s when people were arguing the relative expressive power of various control-flow constructs.
2. Replace the loop with a recursive function, and replace every mutable local variable with a parameter to that function.  Voilà!  Iteration replaced by recursion.

This procedure amounts to writing an interpreter for the original function.  As you may imagine, it results in unreadable code, and it is not an interesting thing to do.  *However*, some of the techniques can be useful for a person with background in imperative programming who is learning to program in a functional language for the first time.

Comment: Aw, @Norman, it is an interesting thing to do.. for a compiler. In fact the procedure is: transform imperative code to functional code, then, transform functional code to imperative code. Why is this interesting? Because the functional code has simple semantics but can't be executed, whereas the imperative output is incomprehensible but suitable for execution. In particular the functional code is easy to optimise for high level things and the imperative code for low level things (but the initial mix is hard to work with for any purpose).

Comment: The real uninteresting things are the semantics of those control primitives to be simulated by recursion function calls. While sometimes they may make the _intent_ behind the source code clearer, it often make difficulties to _reason about the things they actually do_, besides simulating the execution in the original contexts. OTOH, function calls have well-known methods to be reduced quickly for experienced users. The differences are like whether you have the permission to use some equations (rather than doing all things arithmetically)  to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Like you say, every iterative approach can be turned into a "recursive" one, and with tail calls, the stack will not explode either. :-) In fact, that's actually how Scheme implements all common forms of looping. Example in Scheme:

```
(define (fib n)
  (do ((x 0 y)
       (y 1 (+ x y))
       (i 1 (+ i 1)))
      ((> i n) x)))
```

Here, although the function looks iterative, it actually recurses on an internal lambda that takes three parameters, `x`, `y`, and `i`, and calling itself with new values at each iteration.

Here's one way that function could be macro-expanded:

```
(define (fib n)
  (letrec ((inner (lambda (x y i)
                    (if (> i n) x
                        (inner y (+ x y) (+ i 1))))))
    (inner 0 1 1)))
```

This way, the recursive nature becomes more visually apparent.

Comment: And do note that *any* iterative algorithm can be turned into a tail-recursive algorithm. For instance, just transform it to continuation-passing style.

Comment: I would just add that not every language compiler optimizes tail calls, so the stack can indeed "explode" (overflow) in those languages using tail recursion (ex. C#).

Answer (score 8):

Defining iterative as:

```
function q(vars):
  while X:
    do Y
```

Can be translated as:

```
 function q(vars):
    if X:
      do Y
      call q(vars)
```

Y in most cases would include incrementing a counter that is tested by X. This variable will have to be passed along in 'vars' in some way when going the recursive route.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by plinth in the [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively/2093703#2093703) we can construct proofs showing how [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and iteration are equivalent and can both be used to solve the same problem; however, even though we know the two are equivalent there are drawbacks to use one over the other.

In languages that are not optimized for recursion you may find that an algorithm using iteration preforms faster than the recursive one and likewise, even in optimized languages you may find that an algorithm using iteration written in a different language runs faster than the recursive one. Furthermore, there may not be an obvious way of written a given algorithm using recursion versus iteration and vice versa. This can lead to code that is difficult to read which leads to maintainability issues.

Answer (score -2):

Prolog is recursive only language and you can do pretty much everything in it (I don't suggest you do, but you can :))

Answer (score -4):

**Recursive Solutions** are usually **relatively inefficient** when compared to iterative solutions.
However, it is noted that there are some problems that can be solved only through recursion and equivalent iterative solution may not exist or extremely complex to program easily (Example of such is **The Ackermann function** cannot be expressed without recursion)Though recursions are elegant,easy to write and understand.

Comment: "Ackermann function cannot be expressed without recursion" This is not true. How do you think recursion is implemented in a computer? The CPU operates iteratively on a sequence of instructions. To support function calls, including recursive calls, it manages a *stack*. Using recursion is simply letting the *language* (OS, runtime, etc.) manage a stack for you. Any recursive algorithm can be replaced with an iterative one where you manage the stack yourself, including Ackermann.