# For every recursive algorithm there can be created equivalent non-recursive version?

Tags: recursion

Recursion is fun. However, in safety-critical application it is regarded as a dangerous thing (because of stack overflow I suppose?).

Imagine you need to deal with a your favorite language's subset, that would not allow recursion - would that a disaster for you?

Formal question: for every recursive function there could be created a totally equivalent non-recursive one - is that true? is there a theorem about it or something?

Comment: Have you checked SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively

Comment: Recursion is NOT fun... it makes my brain hurt.

Comment: Recursion is great. It's much simpler than loops w.r.t. program verification and it leads to beautiful code.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: What really hurts my brain is emulating recursion. Some algorithms simply are expressed better with recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes every such function can be rewritten as a non-recursive one. I'm not sure there's a formal way to do it, but it is referred to as "recursion unrolling" or "recursion unfolding" in literature.

In most situations, recursion is to be avoided. Especially in the mentioned kind of systems, MISRA-C bans recursion for example.

There are a few rare situations where recursion is handy and makes the code more efficient, some binary tree implementations etc.

But the main purpose of recursion is to teach it to confused students, so that when they become experienced, they can teach it to confused students, so that-...
:)

Comment: The canonical and formal way to do it is the [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) conversion. This is essentially error-prone for humans. Any sane algorithmic language _should have been supported_ it or some equivalent methods via the implementations (e.g. compilers). The fact of banning recursion calls in the source code is really stupid in this sense, because it promotes disabled language designs which _encourage_ errors.

Comment: I know you wrote this long ago, but that is pretty limited view of recursion. Recursion can be done safely especially in languages where tail recursion is a feature and not just a potential optimization.

Comment: @2-bits Yep. Languages that are so notoriously slow that it doesn't matter what you do anyway, predestined to end up with a reeking river of byte code bloat, through which the ferry man known as the garbage collector slowly paddles, apathetically picking through the refuse.

Comment: More languages allow that than just Scheme. Haskell, Kotlin, Scala, F# and even C# (in the right circumstances) can all handle tail calls in such a way that they will never blow the stack, and some, like Haskell, can be quite fast.

Any language *should* be able to do this, but with some it is a requirement rather than an optimization. GCC does this for C (with optimizations on), which I'm sure you wouldn't call slow.

Recursion *is* useful. "Appropriate for embedded systems" is a yardstick many programmers will never have to use and in my view not a good reason to dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like this: your program is executed by a finite set of CPUs (let's assume you have 1 at the moment), executing a sequence of instructions.  How does the CPU handle recursion?  It cannot create a new instance of itself solving a slightly simpler problem, so it uses a stack to keep track of where it is.  So, for any algorithm you can express recursively in any programming language, you can also manually "unroll" the recursion the same way the CPU does, using a stack.  (Note that for many algorithms, particularly ones with only one recursive call, there are usually simpler ways to remove the recursion, such as simple iteration.)

Comment: Also note that for many other algorithms (like tree traversal), the only viable way of removing recursion is manually managing a stack. Also note that this is not even remotely fun so you should just stick to recursion in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually recursion is used because there is no easy way to know how many times you'll need to iterate over a problem.

Replacing a recursive function with simple looping may require a lot of extra work, but should usually be possible if you feel it necessary.

There's little danger of stack overflow if your recursive function has a proper base case, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Recursion is not free**

It takes a considerable amount of memory space (usually on the stack)
And CPU time (by using calls, rebuilding stack frames etc).
In tight loops this makes a recursive algorithm slower than its non-recursive equivalent.

If speed and stack limits are not an issue, by all means leave the recursion in, but if you use recursion in a tight loop, *(which is often the case)*
You gain a lot of optimization options by straitening out the recursion.

Because: maybe:
 1. You don't need to save all those registers/variables
 2. You don't have to jump back to the exact same place where you come from.
 3. You don't need to call that cleanup code for every recursion
 4. You can unroll some loops
 5. You can use an `inline` directive on that non-recursive routine.

My mean issue with recursion is the datastructure it most often is used on: **trees**.

Trees require pointers and pointers require random memory access *(they jump all over the place)*  this is bad for cache usage because sequential access is much faster than random access.
If you replace a binary tree with an 2D array you will waste 50% of the space, *(unless you stack another tree upside down in the array)*, but you gain sequential access options for many of the leaves and you don't have to use pointers, saving space.

```
Example of a binary tree stored in an array
+-----------------+
|0eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee| //no pointers needed, parent/child, is y dimension,
|11       dddddddd| //sibbling is x dimension of the array.
|2222         cccc|  //The 123 tree is stored root up.
|33333333       bb|  //Notice how the abc-tree is stored upside down 
|4444444444444444a|  //The wasted space in the middle, is offset by the fact 
+-----------------+  //that you do not need up, down, and sibbling pointers.
```