# Are all problems that are solvable with recursion solvable with loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, language-agnostic, recursion

All problems that are solvable with recursion are solvable with loop, and vice versa.

Is this statement right or proven at all?
sometimes, using recursion causes stack overflow.
if the statement is correct. we'd better use loop instead.

thanks

Comment: "Solving with a loop" usually means using the heap to store the stack instead of the thread's call stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can all iterative algorithms be expressed recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively)

Comment: I deleted my answer as I discovered a this is a duplicate, but stack overflows are an artificial limitation (bound by call stack size since function calls push another frame onto the stack). Some languages/compilers can 'optimize' away certain types of recursion, such as Tail Call Elimination, to avoid such stack overflow issues.

Comment: That's not a duplicate - this one asks for recursive -> iterative, the other one for iterative -> recursive

Comment: @ltjax - the answer is the same - they might ask for different directions, but the answers in the other question mention that recursion and iteration are equivalent.

Comment: @birryree I believe that SO policy is that two different questions that have the same answer are not considered  duplicates.

Comment: @Raedwald - Fair enough, I was being overzealous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Loop + Stack will solve all recursion problems.

After all, compiler does that internally. Recursion is nothing but pushing data onto a stack, and later popping from it, done by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the corresponding iterative (looping) solution will need just as much storage, but will need to manage it explicitly.