# Can every recursive function be rewritten as an iterative function?

Tags: recursion, iteration, computer-science

I've had this question on my mind for a really long time but I can't figure out the answer. The question is, if does every recursive function have an iterative function that does the same?

For example,

```
factorial(n) {
    if (n==1) { return 1 }
    else      { return factorial(n-1) }
}
```

This can be easily rewritten iteratively:

```
factorial(n) {
    result = 1;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        result *= i
    }
    return result
}
```

But there are many other, more complicated recursive functions, so I don't know the answer in general. This might also be a theoretical computer science question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a recursive function can always be written as an iteration, from a theoretical point of view - this has been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2093618/201359). Quoting from the linked post:

> Because you can build a Turing complete language using strictly iterative structures and a Turning complete language using only recursive structures, then the two are therefore equivalent.

Explaining a bit: we know that any computable problem can be solved by a Turing machine. And it's possible to construct a programming language `A` without recursion, that is equivalent to a Turing machine. Similarly, it's possible to build a programming language `B` without iteration, equal in computational power to a Turing machine.

Therefore, if both `A` and `B` are [Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) we can conclude that for any iterative program there must exist an equivalent recursive program, and vice versa. This is a theoretical result, in the sense that it doesn't give you any hints on how to derive one recursive program from an arbitrary iterative program, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Without going to theory, it is easy to convince oneself that any recursive function can have an iterative equivalent by observing that processors (such as Pentium) just run iteratively.