# Can Every Iterative method can be done using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Hi This a very generic question.
I Want to know can whether every Iterative method(using loops) can be done using recursion?

Comment: YES !! :)
Already answered here - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively

Answer (score 0):

> I Want to know can whether every Iterative method(using loops) can be
>   done using recursion?

Yes, see [Church–Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), it proves this.

Useful links:

- [Replace Iteration with Recursion](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceIterationWithRecursion.html)
- [Can all iterative algorithms be modelled recursively and vice-versa?](http://www.quora.com/Can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-modelled-recursively-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Some great explanations can be found [here](http://www.quora.com/Can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-modelled-recursively-and-vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized iterative function :-

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

   doSomething(i);

}
```

Here is equivalent recursive function :-

```
recfunc(int i,int n) {

  if(i<n) {

       doSomething(i); 
       recfunc(i+1,n);

  }

}
```