# Recursive and Iterative approach

Tags: recursion, iteration

The way every recursive version has an iterative version as well is this right saying that vice-versa is also true (i.e. every iterative version has recursive version)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can all iterative algorithms be expressed recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618/can-all-iterative-algorithms-be-expressed-recursively)

Answer (score -1):

In recursive approach, the function calls itself until the condition is met, whereas, in iterative approach, a function repeats until the condition fails.